# Passed Latitude and Longitude between two intent

Tags: android

Having an  activity  which have a latitude and longitude save as string and in other activity in same package  want it to open in the same latitude and longitude the first activity have so how can i pass data between both activities  . if this what i want to path from intent to other

```
enter code here
loc.getLatitude(); 
loc.getLongitude();
```

Loc is location its the GPS get Double for both .

```
enter code here
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yaraby.y/yaraby.y.yaraby}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at yaraby.y.yaraby.onCreate(yaraby.java:49)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
 06-19 22:18:34.720: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2523):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: So what you are asking is "how is it possible to pass parameter from on intent to another one"... nothing related to latitude or longitude generally.

Comment: yes and How to Pass the Location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your sender activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivty.class);
i.putExtra("latitude", loc.getLatitude());
i.putExtra("longitude", loc.getLongitude());
startActivity(i);
```

and this in your receiver activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
double latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
double longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
```

Thats it! Good luck!

Comment: put the bundle statement in the onCreate of your receiver activity.

Comment: here are the error i'm having 3 Intent Yarab , yaraby , ghost  
yarab is the intent that open for the 2 intent and here is the error i want to send data from yaraby to ghost while both just open from yarab

Answer (score 0):

The error you see has nothing to do with your intent extras.
Your trying to access an EditText but what you get is something different (or vice versa, not sure).

Take a look at yaraby.y.yaraby.onCreate(yaraby.java:49) (Line 49) and make sure you are casting to the right type. Probably you have something like this there:

```
var = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourWidgetId)
```

Problem is what you get is in fact not an EditText.